# Removing full text search results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm currently using CONTAINSTABLE as part of a full text search, but can not work out how to produce a negative search. e.g. 
contains: hot dogs
does not contain: pet health issues

My current search works great for finding things, but how can I add in the negative terms to remove the articles with references to pet health issues.

I hope that makes sense, I've tried searching for CONTAINSTABLE negative, exclude ect but can't find anything.

Edit:
It's probably not the most efficient solution, but would creating a temp table containing the 'does not contain' results and then adding AND NOT IN (temp table) to the original query. be a very bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server FTS has a not keyword; you should be able to do

```
containstable(*,'"hot dogs and not "pet health issues")
```

Comment: Actually should say if you are using * rather than specifying a column in your contains table SQL Server FTS runs the filter as an OR's  across columns which can give confusing results.

Comment: That's great, AND NOT is working fine. The column is specified from the start so no issues there.